# SQLDeveloper: How to view Connection box and browse through the schema of DB

Tags: user-interface, oracle-sqldeveloper

I remember that I used to view "Connection" pallete where I could browse whole schema of DB through collapse/show UI.
[image]
Somehow that UI is not visible, can someone please help tell me how to enable that UI. I tried enabling/disabling and changing view of SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: "Windows" => "Reset Windows to factory settings"

You will be able to see this UI now:

[image]